# ASP.NET Web API and Ninject not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I started a new ASP.NET MVC project and I'm using Ninject as my IOC controller.

As far as regular MVC Controllers goes - everything work fine and binding is done to the controller constructor as expected.

I've added a WEB API to my project and did pretty much the same thing. here is the API constructor:

```
public class DetailsController : ApiController
{
    private IClientInfoRetriever _clientInfoRetriever;

    public DetailsController(IClientInfoRetriever clientInfoRetriever)
    {
        _clientInfoRetriever = clientInfoRetriever;
    }

    .
    .
    .
    // The rest of my methods
}
```

here is the Ninject binding:

```
Bind<IClientInfoRetriever>().To<ClientInfoRetriever>();
```

but when I try to access my API (just putting the URL in the browser for a get action) I get the following error:

An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DetailsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

It's expecting to get an empty constructor, but if I give it an empty constructor to use - it won't be initializing the object I need.

What am I doing wrong? does Ninject support web api?

Thanks

Comment: Read http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/using-ninject-with-the-latest-asp-net-web-api-source/

Comment: this article was written when web apis were still in beta and pre-release - is it even still relevant?

Comment: Maybe ninject has a package for web api integration, at least autofac has one

Comment: You'll need the [Ninject.Web.WebApi package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the proper Ninject Nuget package for WebAPI:

```
PM> Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebApi -Version 3.0.0.2
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting the following error while trying to install: Already referencing a newer version of 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.

Comment: ok. ended up downloading from pre-release - that did the trick. thanks.

Comment: pre-release also getting same issue